# Is it possible to get timestamps from Web Speech Recognition API?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I don't see anything in the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) but thought I would check here as well.

Is it possible to get the timestamp of each recognized word in a sentence?
I'm using the below code to listen for a sentence.

```
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.lang = "en-US";
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

recognition.start();

recognition.onresult = function (event) {
  console.log(event.results);
};
```

This is the result I get:

```
{0: Object, length: 1, item: ƒ item()}
0: Object
0: Object
transcript: "drink water from tap"
confidence: 0.9446192979812622
length: 1
isFinal: true
item: ƒ item() {}
<constructor>: "Function"
length: 1
item: ƒ item() {}
<constructor>: "Function"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in JavaScript using SpeechRecognition to calculate the time stamp for each word separately:

```js
const recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition(); // initialize SpeechRecognition

let startTimeStamp = 0;  // start time for the first word
let endTimeStamp = 0;  // end time for each spoken word
let timeElapsed = 0;   // time elapsed from start to end of each spoken word

recognition.onstart = function() {
  console.log("Voice recognition started. Speak now."); // log voice recognition has started to console
};

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  const transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript.trim(); // get the spoken transcript of the recognized words
  
  const words = transcript.split(" "); // split the transcript into an array of words
  
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    
    if (i === 0) {
        startTimeStamp = event.timeStamp; // set start time for the first word
        console.log(`Start time for word '${words[i]}': ${startTimeStamp}`); // log start time to console
    }
    
    endTimeStamp = event.timeStamp; // set end time for each word
    timeElapsed = endTimeStamp - startTimeStamp; // calculate time elapsed between start and end of each spoken word
    
    console.log(`End time for word '${words[i]}': ${endTimeStamp}`); // log end time to console
    console.log(`Time elapsed for word '${words[i]}': ${timeElapsed}`); // log time elapsed to console

    startTimeStamp = endTimeStamp; // set start time for the next word
  }
};

recognition.start(); // start SpeechRecognition
```

This code uses the SpeechRecognition API to recognize spoken words and calculate the start and end times of each word, as well as the time elapsed between the start and end of each spoken word. The code logs the start time, end time, and time elapsed for each word to the console.